# How to change datatypes on the fly in Copy activity IN Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]

Here am copying from Oracle db to Parquet ,here i dont find any option to change datatype because import schema detected date col as INT96 . So how to change back to Date col ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, In parquet files the `DateTimeOffset` means `Int_96` type only. Thats why it is detecting the type as `Int96`.

Here for sample I am copying the below SQL table with date data to a parquet file of same schema.

[image]

when I import the mapping of source and sink in copy activity, you can see I got same.

[image]

But, when we see the symbol of `INT_96` it is date time symbol. It means when data is copying into parquet file the date time type data of source will be copied to date time type(means `INT_96` in parquet type).

And I am able copy without any issues here.

[image]

When I interchange the source and sink datasets in the copy activity, it recognized it as Date type.

[image]

This behavior is might be because of the parquet file type nature. But it indicates that when you use your target parquet file in any source, it will be recognized as Date type only which is your required type.

When sink is parquet, you can see the type as date only for that column in the Pipeline JSON mapping.

[image]

> So how to change back to Date col ?

If you want to change you can edit the `physicalType` from `INT_96` to date in mapping of the Pipeline JSON.

**mapping After changing pipeline JSON:**

[image]

(Or) you can use dataflows in ADF to change the data type. Use Cast transformation in the data flows.

[image]

Comment: In mapping of Copy activity ,there is no option to change the datatype . Thats what i asked , i cant see any option . to change the dattypes in copy activity ,ofcourse i can use Dataflow , but i need just one copy activity . Can i do it or not.

Comment: You can edit the mapping in the Pipeline JSON as mentioned in the above picture.